# Flask/Nginx/Uwsgi Gateway 504 error, "SIGPIPE: writing to a closed pipe/socket/fd (probably the client disconnected) on request"

Tags: python-3.x, flask

I'm making an app that lets the user upload a csv of data, and generates a plot of that data, saves the plot to a pdf, then returns the plot as a download to the user. The crux of the issue is that in reality, this plot takes 1 - 2 minutes to generate.

### The App

The route is as follows:

```
@app.route("/gen_pdf", methods=["GET","POST"])
def transform2():
    f = request.files['input_file1']
    if not f:
        return "Main input file not found!"

    # Read uploaded data as a Stream into a dataframe. 
    stream = io.StringIO(f.stream.read().decode("UTF8"), newline=None)
    csv_input = csv.reader(stream)
    contents = []
    for row in csv_input:
        contents.append(float(row[0]))

    #Artificially increase time required to generate plot
    time.sleep(60)
    plt.hist(contents, bins=100)
    fn = "test_histogram.pdf"
    plt.savefig(app.config["CLIENT_DIR"]+"/"+fn)

    return send_from_directory(app.config["CLIENT_DIR"], filename=fn, as_attachment=True)
```

`gen_pdf.html`, for completeness (this can just be embedded within some html boilerplate)

```
{% extends "layout.html" %}
{% block content %}
    <h1>Test</h1>
    <hr/>
    <form action="/transform2" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
      <h3>Upload input file (csv)</h3>
      <input type="file" name="input_file1" id="input_file1">
      <hr/>
      <input type="submit" value="Create and Serve PDF" name="submit">
    </form>
{% endblock content %}
```

The data to be uploaded are just a single csv file with a single column of randomly generated numbers.

### Nginx/Uwsgi Setup

These were set up on a Ubuntu 18.04 VM, following the setup [here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-serve-flask-applications-with-uswgi-and-nginx-on-ubuntu-18-04).

### The Error

As mentioned, this leads to a gateway 504 error. However, if I reduce the delay in the `time.sleep()` command to, say, 10s, everything works just fine, so the error somehow stems from something timing out before the pdf plot is completed.

When checking `journalctl --unit=<my_project>.service -n 100 --no-pager`, I get:

```
SIGPIPE: writing to a closed pipe/socket/fd (probably the client disconnected) on request /transform2 (ip <ip_address>) !!!
uwsgi_response_writev_headers_and_body_do(): Broken pipe [core/writer.c line 306] during POST /transform2 (<ip_address>)
OSError: write error
[pid: 27863|app: 0|req: 156/335] <ip_address> () {50 vars in 1083 bytes} [Mon Jul 27 02:18:38 2020] POST /transform2 => generated 0 bytes in 60835 msecs (HTTP
```

I'm aware of the explanation of the SIGPIPE error [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45209613/what-does-this-uwsgi-error-mean-sigpipe-writing-to-a-closed-pipe-socket-fd), but that explanation doesn't seem relevant (it's an internal process, not between visitors).

I've also tried the solutions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24127601/uwsgi-request-timeout-in-python) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6672073/djangonginxuwsgi-504-gateway-time-out/11961343) because they look like similar errors, to no avail.

Answer (score 1):

For posterity, the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6672073/djangonginxuwsgi-504-gateway-time-out/11961343) was indeed correct: add the line `uwsgi_read_timeout 600s;` in the appropriate location block.

After that, *restart nginx for the new config to take effect*: `systemctl restart nginx`. This was the missing step.

Comment: I don't have nginx, is there a way to force this using just uwsgi?

Comment: @DJ_Stuffy_K yes, you want all three of the uWSGI settings `ignore-sigpipe`, `ignore-write-errors`, and `disable-write-exception`. Each corresponds to inhibiting one of the error lines above. You can typically replicate the issue by hammering on the F5 (refresh) key rapidly on a uWSGI hosted URL.